# How to add the Unity generated UWP project (C++) into Existing C# UWP project

Tags: c#, c++, unity-game-engine, uwp

My question is can we integrate the Unity generated C++ UWP project into C# UWP project and how to call the pages in that C++ project inside a C# project.

Is there any alternate solution for this?

[image: This is my Unity generated C++ project[![][1]]

[image]

Comment: why ... don't you generate a C# project from unity?

Comment: .net scripting is deprecated

Comment: what do you mean? C# is the main language of Unity.

Comment: while generating the UWP project .net scripting is deprecated only IL2CPP  is supported

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187997/discussion-between-nandha-and-bolov).